# Finding values in multi dimensional array that sloped by number using recursion (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Im trying to make a multi dimensional array that contains numbers and I need to find the number neighbors (down or right) that slope by num(variable)
example :
{7,5,3},{1,5,9}
the numbers 3,5,7 are sloped by 2 and the counter is 3 ( 3 numbers )
I need to find the longest slope which means that if there slope with 3 numbers and also after that slope with 6 numbers I need to return the 6 numbers.. 
I tried already for about 5 hours but im completely lost , here is my code until now :

```
private static int longestSlope (int [][] mat, int num , int i , int j , int count , int temp,int oldi,int oldj) 
{
    System.out.println("oldi " +oldi);
    System.out.println("oldj " +oldj);
    System.out.println("temp " +temp);
    System.out.println("count "+count);
    System.out.println("i "+i);
    System.out.println("j "+j);



    if(i < mat.length-1 && j < mat[0].length-1 )
    {


        if(j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] - num == mat[i][j+1] )
        {
            if(temp == 0)
            {
                oldj = j;
                oldi = i;
            }
            if(j == mat[0].length-1)
            {

                return longestSlope(mat,num,i,j,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj);

            }
            else
            {

                temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i,j+1,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj);

            }

        }
        else if(i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] - num == mat[i+1][j])
        {

            if(temp == 0)
            {
                oldj = j;
                oldi = i;
            }
            temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i+1,j,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj);
        }
        else 
            temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i,j+1,count,temp,oldi,oldj);

    }

    else if(i < mat.length-1 && j == mat[0].length-1 && temp == 0)
    {
        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i+1,0,count,0,oldi,oldj);
    }

    else if(temp > count)
    {
        count = temp;
        System.out.println("nihnas "+count);
        return longestSlope(mat,num,oldi,oldj+1,count,0,0,0);
    }
    else if(temp < count)
    {

        longestSlope(mat,num,oldi,oldj+1,count,0,0,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. Can you explain more?

Comment: Please add hard coded test data and expected output.

Comment: That's the multi dimensional array :
{3 13 15 28 30} 
,{55 54 53 27 26} 
,{54 12 52 51 50} 
,{50 10 8 53 11}    , the output should be if num = 1 : 6 , because from [1][0] to [1][2] its 3 and then from [2][2] to [2][3] its 2 so it will be 6 , num its the slope that the user want , the slope can be to the right or to down.