# Multi dimelsional slop using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

That's the multi dimensional array :

```
{ 3 13 15 28 30} ,
{55 54 53 27 26} ,
{54 12 52 51 50} ,
{50 10  8 53 11} ,
```

The output should be `if num = 1 : 6` , because from [1][0] to [1][2] its 3 and then from [2][2] to [2][3] its 2 so it will be 6 , `num` its the slope that the user want , the slope can be to the right or to down , its forbidden to use loop of any kind , only recursion, tried for like 8 hours to solve it but i am so confused , here is my code :

```
private static int longestSlope (int [][] mat, int num , int i , int j , int count , int temp,int oldi,int oldj,boolean found) 
    {
        System.out.println("oldi " +oldi);
        System.out.println("oldj " +oldj);
        System.out.println("temp " +temp);
        System.out.println("count "+count);
        System.out.println("i "+i);
        System.out.println("j "+j);


        if(i == mat.length-1 && j == mat[0].length-1)
            return count;

        if(i != mat.length && j != mat[0].length) 
        {               

                if(j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] - num == mat[i][j+1] ) // keep j+
                {

                    if(temp == 0)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        oldj = j;
                        oldi = i;
                    }
                        System.out.println("check2");
                    if(j == 0)
                        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i,j+1,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj,found);
                    else
                        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i,j+1,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj+1,found);


                }
                else if(i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] - num == mat[i+1][j])
                {

                    if(temp == 0)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        oldj = j;
                        oldi = i;
                    }
                    temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i+1,j,count,temp+1,oldi,oldj,found);
                }
                else if(j < mat[0].length-1)
                    temp = longestSlope(mat,num,i,j+1,count,temp,oldi,oldj,found);
                else if(found)
                {
                    System.out.println(found);
                    System.out.println("found i "+i);
                    System.out.println("found j "+j);
                    found = false;
                    if(j != mat[0].length-1)
                        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,oldi,oldj,count,0,oldi,oldj,found);
                    else if(j == mat[0].length-1 && temp != 0)
                        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,oldi,oldj,count,0,oldi,oldj,found);
                    else
                        temp = longestSlope(mat,num,oldi+1,0,count,0,oldi,oldj,found);
                }
            }


            if(i < mat.length-1 && !found)
            {

                System.out.println("oldj222222222 "+oldj);
                return longestSlope(mat,num,i+1,0,count,0,0,0,found);
            }
            return 0;           

    }
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @GBlodgett the code has alot of bugs and it doesn't return the count

Comment: Your definition of `slope` is really unclear. I don't see where `from [1][0] to [1][2] its 3 ` etc. relates to the matrix that you gave. Please clarify the definition. Also "Has a lot of bugs" is not clear, either. What is the output that you get? Do you have errors? Do you get different problems under different inputs?

Comment: By slop do you mean the difference between two adjacent cells ?  So `[1][0]` is 55 and  `[1][2] ` is 54  and the difference is 1.  I also can't figure out why `from [1][0] to [1][2] its 3` . Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983579/finding-values-in-multi-dimensional-array-that-sloped-by-number-using-recursion) and clarify.